# sas horizontal bar chart-Making labels same size

Tags: charts, sas

I'm using a macro to generate many similar horizontal bar charts. The chart width changes according to the labels (on the vertical axis) length.

How I can make all the charts the same width causing the labels to wrap automatically to adjust?

```
data my_annoDetailedChart&i; set FinalDim&i;
        xsys='2'; ysys='2'; hsys='3'; when='a';
        group=itemname;
        midpoint=entity;
        x=score;
        function='label'; position='>'; color='grayaa'; size=1.5;
        text="   "||trim(left(put(score,comma5.2)));

        goptions device=png;
        goptions xpixels=700 ypixels=450;
        goptions noborder;
        goptions cback=white;

        goptions gunit=pct ftitle="albany amt/bold" ftext="albany amt" hsize=6.5 vsize= 7.6 inches
         htitle=4.1 htext=1.5 ctext=gray44;************************************************************************************************************;
        *---Indicators---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------;
        pattern1 v=solid c=navy; /* blue */
        pattern2 v=solid c=lightgray; /* green */
        pattern1 v=solid c=navy; /* blue */
        pattern2 v=solid c=lightgray; /* green */
        axis1 SPLIT="*" label=none order=(1 to 5 by .5) minor=none offset=(0,0)
         color=graydd major=(color=gray44) value=(color=gray44);
        axis2 SPLIT="*" label=none value=none ;
        axis3 label=none offset=(3,3);*  order=( &KOko);

        legend1 position=(bottom right inside) mode=share label=none  shape=bar(.15in,.15in) offset=(-1,-0.1);
        proc gchart data=FinalDim&i anno=my_annoDetailedChart&i;
        hbar entity / discrete type=sum sumvar=Score nostat
        subgroup=entity group=itemname  space=0 gspace=1
        raxis=axis1 maxis=axis2 gaxis=axis3 autoref 
        legend=legend1   clipref   ;
        title color=navy   h=6 font="Times New Roman"  "&Dimension";
```

Comment: Do you have SAS 9.4?

Comment: no I have 9.3 version